# Rails kaminari per_page url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, api, kaminari

i try to use kaminari gem with my REST API and MongoDB,
so far i can use **http://127.0.0.1:3000?page=1** to paginate result.

Is there any way to set (per_page attr) from url, like:

**http://127.0.0.1:3000?page=1&per_page=10**

??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `per` scope: see https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari#query-basics

The query will be formed as follows:

```
@objects.page(params[:page]).per(params[:per_page])
```

Comment: This is it, thak you.

Comment: Awesome. Do mark the answer as selected if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

you can specify default per_page value per each model using a declarative DSL method paginates_per.

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  paginates_per 10
end
```

or You can do this:
You can configure the following default values by overriding these values using Kaminari.configure method.

```
default_per_page  # 25 by default
max_per_page      # nil by default
max_pages         # nil by default
window            # 4 by default
outer_window      # 0 by default
left              # 0 by default
right             # 0 by default
page_method_name  # :page by default
param_name        # :page by default
```

There's a handy generator that generates the default configuration file into config/initializers directory. Run the following generator command, then edit the generated file.

```
% rails g kaminari:config
```

or just do:

```
@obj.page(params[:page]).per(10)
```